# Update table based on other tables

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to implement the below Logic with an SQL Statement? If implemented, will there be any potential risk of performance while dealing 4000 orders at a time frame of 30 Mins. We have SQL Server as our database.

I have 2 Tables as below.

**Orders**

Cust_ID   Cust_WHID   Emp_ID   Latitude   Longitude
C10001   WH142001   ??????   13.051738   77.629877
C10002   WH142001   ??????   13.047688   77.629279
C10003   WH142001   ??????   13.043722   77.623373
C10004   WH142002   ??????   13.047213   77.628853

**User_Validation**
User_ID         User_WHID   Latitude         Longitude   Current_Capacity
EMP100001   WH100001   13.033304   77.636592            5
EMP100002   WH100001   13.032645   77.629908            3
EMP100003   WH100001   13.046191   77.625797            0
EMP100004   WH100002   13.044981   77.626154            2
EMP100005   WH100002   13.052305   77.631151            4
EMP100006   WH100002   13.051004   77.630786            0

Now i want to update the Emp_ID Field in Orders table with the below criteria.

1. Find Number of employees per Warehouse from User_Validation Table.
2. Find nearest employee to the Customer by comparing the Latitude and Longitude of employee in User_Validation table to the latitude and longitude of the customer in Order table.
3. The nearest employee Current_Capacity should not exceeding 6.
4. If it is already 6 then find next near employee with out max capacity and so on until an employee is found.
5. If all the employees has full capacity as 6 then assign the nearest employee ID to the customer

I tried the below logic which i know it is not going to work when there are multiple records. I tried with a single record even , but got errors in the statement.

```
Update Orders Set Emp_ID=User_Validation.User_ID from (Select User_ID from 
User_Validation where Current_Capacity <='6' and (SELECT Top 1 User_ID, (( 6367450 * 
acos(   cos( radians(Orders.Latitude) ) * cos( radians( User_Validation.Latitude ) ) * 
cos(   radians( User_Validation.Longitude ) - radians(Orders.Longitude) ) + sin(   
radians(Orders.Latitude) ) * sin( radians( User_Validation.Latitude ) ) ) )) AS   
distance_Mtrs FROM Orders, User_Validation order by distance_Mtrs)) where   
Orders.Cust_WHID=User_Validation.User_WHID
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps following query may guide you

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    Cust_ID, Cust_WHID,
    User_ID, User_WHID, Current_Capacity,
    case when Current_Capacity >= 6 then 1 else 0 end as isfull,
    dbo.fnGetDistance(o.Latitude, o.Longitude, e.Latitude, e.Longitude, 'Meters') distance
FROM Orders o, User_Validation e
--  ORDER BY Current_Capacity
), cte2 as (
select *, row_number() over (order by distance, isfull, Current_Capacity) rn
from cte
--  ORDER BY distance, isfull, Current_Capacity
)
select * from cte2
where rn = 1
--ORDER BY distance, isfull, Current_Capacity
```

I used the user function prepared by Jim Jackson for calculating distance ( please refer to http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2009/02/13/calculating-distances-between-latitude-and-longitude-t-sql-haversine.aspx )

Comment: Hi Eralper..Am checking the Query..I will let you know in few mins.

Comment: Hi Eralper...Am getting the following issue....dbo.fnGetDistance could not be found...Am using sql server 2008